# `In HDL file home/barnacles/nand2tetris/projects/01/And.hdl,Line 18, ',', or ')' are expected`

Tags: architecture, boolean, digital, nand2tetris

I keep on receiving the error:

`In HDL file home/barnacles/nand2tetris/projects/01/And.hdl,Line 18, ',', or ')' are expected`

And I keep on checking the syntax and it's correct and I don't know what is wrong.

```
// This file is part of www.nand2tetris.org
// and the book "The Elements of Computing Systems"
// by Nisan and Schocken, MIT Press.
// File name: projects/01/And.hdl

/**
 * And gate: 
 * out = 1 if (a == 1 and b == 1)
 *       0 otherwise
 */

CHIP And {
    IN a, b;
    OUT out;

    PARTS:
    // Put your code here:
    Nand(a=a, b=b, out=nand_1);
    Not(in=nand_1, out=out);
}
```

```
// This file is part of www.nand2tetris.org
// and the book "The Elements of Computing Systems"
// by Nisan and Schocken, MIT Press.
// File name: projects/01/And.hdl

/**
 * And gate: 
 * out = 1 if (a == 1 and b == 1)
 *       0 otherwise
 */

CHIP And {
    IN a, b;
    OUT out;

    PARTS:
    // Put your code here:
    Nand(a=a, b=b, out=nand_1);
    Nand(a=nand_1, b=nand_1, out=out);
}
```

I know the changes are saving. I also tried reinstalling

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that _ is not a valid character for a symbol name. If you change nand_1 to nand1, your HDL should compile.

This limitation is unexpected and new to me, and it doesn't help that the error message is cryptic. If it had even gone so far as to provide the character position in the line that triggered the error, the problem would have been much more obvious.